# ggplot line plot with different line styles for over 13 lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph a line plot with ggplot that has 15 lines. I want the lines to be varied to make it easier to read. I found a way to make the lines vary from dotted, dashed, and straight, however, it only works for up to 13 variables and then will not plot the last two. Does anyone have a way to work around this?

Here is an example of what I tried to do.

```
states_list = list('Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Delaware', 'Flordia', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'Oregon', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Utah', 'Washington', 'Vermont')

states_repeat = rep(states_list, 8)


states_df <-data.frame(states = unlist(states_repeat), years = list(rep(2014:2021, times = 15)), value = (rnorm(120)))

colnames(states_df) <- c('states', 'years', 'value')

statesplot <- ggplot(states_df, aes(x = years, y = value, group = states, colour = states)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = states))
            
statesplot
```

Here is what the plot looks like
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTPyz.png)

Comment: I think you're running up against the limit of how many linetypes are available in ggplot - according to this there are 12, so I'm not sure how you got 13. http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype#:~:text=The%20scale_linetype_discrete%20scale%20maps%20up,to%2012%20pre%2Ddefined%20linetypes.

Answer (score 1):

Using a lot of different linetypes is in general not recommended as the lines are hard to distinguish. Perhaps one reason why the default palette for the linotypes provided by `scales::linetype_pal()` provides only a maximum of 13 different linotypes. Be it as it is, if you need more linetypes you could extend the default palette or create your own. For more info on how to create a custom linetype see the [Aesthetic specification](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:line-type-spec) vignette. In the code below I extend the default linetype palette:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

lty_pal <- c(linetype_pal()(13), "1373", "88")

ggplot(states_df, aes(
    x = years,
    y = value,
    group = states,
    colour = states
  )) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = states)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lty_pal)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the resource! That is good to know that its generally not recommended to have many different types of lines. Would it be better to make the colors more distinguishable instead?

Comment: In general using `color`  is preferable to distinguish categories than linetypes. However, the general issue is that more than 8 lines are hard to distinguish. And IMHO there is no optimal solution for the case of more lines and it always depends on what you want so say with your chart. One possible approach which I use quite often would be to use small multiples aka facetting, i.e. one facet per state showing the trend for this state compared to the overall average.